# How to backup mysql dump files from bacula

Tags: permissions, mysql, backup

I'm running Bacula on a Ubuntu 14.04 server. During backup I create the dump files in `/var/lib/bacula/dump`. This part work perfectly. But my files are never backed up. This is the file permissions on the folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct  1 13:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Oct  1 13:34 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 95976275 Oct  1 13:35 smallehowitz.sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38458014 Oct  1 13:35 test.sql
```

Anyone has a clue on this?